# how to use jQuery in Rails helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I am trying to use the tabs function from jQuery UI in a Rails app.  I am using a helper for the navigation and I would like to keep it that way.  The code in my helper is:

```
def links_for_navigation
  html = ""
  html  = <<HTML
   <ul>
     <li><a href="#tabs-1">Courses</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tabs-2">Parts</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tabs-3">Categories</a></li>
   </ul>    
  <div id="tabs-1"><% link_to "Courses", courses_path %>
  <div id="tabs-2"><% link_to "Parts", parts_path %>
  <div id="tabs-3"><% link_to "Categories", categories_path %>
  HTML
end
```

My view pulls in the code with `<% links_for_navigation %>`

I added to my `application.js`:

```
jQuery(function() {
 jQuery("#tabs").tabs();
});
```

And my `application.html.erb` has:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'courses', 'jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.css' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery-1.5.1.min.js', 'jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js', 'application' %>
```

When I try to load the page I get `cannot find string HTML before EOF`.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend using a partial, rather than a helper method. The partial, I'll call it `_nav.html.erb`, would look like the following (note the `id="tabs"` on the surrounding `div`):

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#tabs-1">Courses</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#tabs-2">Parts</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#tabs-3">Categories</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tabs-1">
        <%= link_to "Courses", courses_path %>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <%= link_to "Parts", parts_path %>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <%= link_to "Categories", categories_path %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then in the appropriate view file, you can insert the partial with a call to render:

```
<%= render :partial => 'nav' %>
```

I've never used jQuery tabs but try adding this to `application.js`, based on [this example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/default.html). The `"#tabs"` selector inside `$()` corresponds to the `id="tabs"` from above:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});
```

I'll offer a couple tips/reminders as well:

- Embedded ruby (ERB) tags needs to have an `=` if you want them to print something, i.e. `<%= @user.name %>` versus `<% @user.name %>`. The first will output a string into the file, the second will not. There are cases where you might not want to print something, so you would leave off the `=`.
- Be sure to close all your HTML tags. Rails' ERB files can get messy anyways, so proper HTML structure is key.
- Avoid using HTML outside of `*.html.erb` files. This isn't a golden rule, but it's a good rule of thumb.

Comment: May be stupid question but where does the partial go?  Obviously in views but where?

Comment: Not a stupid question. The answer is: anywhere you'd like, as long as you give the right path. But usually partials are kept in the same folder as the file they are used in. So if you are using the nav partial in `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` you would keep it in `app/views/layouts/`. If you wanted to put it elsewhere, you'll have to declare the path in the call to render: `<%= render :partial => "app/views/otherfolder/nav" %>`.